# Ошибки в операторе сложения базового пакета R

Tags: r, операции

R-4.0.3 [64-bit]

```
counter<-0
counter= counter + 1
```

выдаёт ошибку

> Ошибка в UseMethod("+") :   нет подходящего метода для '+' применяемого к
> объекту класса "c('double', 'numeric')"

```
counter=base::`+`(counter , 1)
```

или

```
counter<-as.integer(counter) + 1
```

Та же ошибка

```
counter= as.integer(counter)
counter= counter + 1
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> Ошибка в UseMethod("+") :   нет подходящего метода для '+'
> применяемого к объекту класса "c('integer', 'numeric')"

В чем может быть проблема?

В гугле или документации R ситуация не описана.

Comment: установил r-base версии 4.0.3, ничего подобного не воспроизводится. 1. у вас чистая установка r, ничего дополнительного? 2. `1+2` приводит к той же ошибке? 3. что выдаёт `class(1); class(counter)`?

Comment: > 1+2
Ошибка в UseMethod("+") :
  нет подходящего метода для '+' применяемого к объекту класса "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: > class(1)
[1] "numeric"
> class(i)
[1] "numeric"

Comment: Похоже что-то подменяет оператор +. Вроде справился.

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, ответ, с результатами ваших изысканий. возможно, это ещё кому-нибудь поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось, что пакет анализа для внутренних нужд компании подменяет оператор `+` из базового набора. Рабочее решение для такой ситуации:

```
counter=base::`+`(counter , 1)
```

Ошибка была в том, что внутри скобок я также использовал оператор + вот так:

```
counter=base::`+`(counter + 1)
```